# SSH access with SSH reverse tunnel

Tags: linux, ssh, ssh-tunnel

I can find a lot tutorials on the web for setting up an reverse SSH tunnel.

```
  ssh -p2000 -fNC -R 10011:localhost:22.user@proxy.de
```

But how I can become an SSH connection on my local server? I like to set up a connection from proxy(has a public IP) to localhost(which is in my home network) through the SSH reverse tunnel . I need to type from anywhere SSH commands on my localhost.

Thanks for your help
Stefan

Comment: It looks like you have already set up the tunnel correctly. What exactly do you need help with?

Comment: On my localhost is only port 80 and 443 open to connect with the internet

Comment: Presumably that is why you have set up the tunnel! So what exactly do you need help with?

Comment: I become this error to day

user@user:~$ ssh -f -N -T -R 2210:localhost:22 User@ip
User@ip's password:
user@user:~$ Warning: remote port forwarding failed for listen port 2210
connect_to locahost: unknown host (Temporary failure in name resolution)

Comment: That's a typo. It's `localhost` not `locahost`.

Comment: i had to reboot both servers and correct the typo.  And now it set up the tunnel

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing about SSH reverse proxies, are you trying from *another* machine/the "proxy server" (?) to connect to a local/'private' hostname of 'localhost' that maps to the local/'private' 'loopback' address that resolves to (IPv4) '127.0.0.1' (or 127.x.x.x even) or (IPv6) '::1', when the loopback address 'resolves'/equates to the local machine, and possibly only if you have a "localhost" entry within your (*NIX - UNIX/Linux) '/etc/hosts' or (Windows) 'C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts' file.

If so, you'd might need to target the proper 'hostname' that is mapped to a proper 'private' IP address (i.e. the one assigned to the NIC/network card) - if they are both on the same network, otherwise possibly a 'public' IP address - unless NAT (Network Address Translation - private IP to public IP conversion/replacement for outgoing & vice versa for incoming) is in place to handle this for you.

Answer (score 0):

To summarize, you have on host **A** (proxy.net) with a public IP and host **B** without a public IP. You want to to enter into an ssh shell on **B** from **A**.

This can be done by forwarding a free port of **A** to the sshd listening port on B.

To achieve this, first if it is not already running start *sshd* either by entering

```
sshd
```

into a shell, or if you have systemd like

```
systemctl start sshd
```

After this, set up a reverse tunnel from **B** to **A** like this:

```
ssh -N -R 8890:localhost:22 <a_user>@proxy.net
```

The port *8890* can be exchanged with any free port on **A**. The port *22* is the port that the ssh deamon *sshd* is listening to on **B**.
Most likely it is *22*, but it could be a different port.
You can find out by running

```
sudo netstat -lntp
```

There should be a line with *sshd* in the *Progam Name* column.
In that line the local address columns should show something like `127.0.0.1:22`. The number behind the `:` is the port your ssh deamon is listening on.

After setting up the remote ssh tunnel, you can ssh into **B** from **A** by running

```
ssh -p 8890 <b_user>@localhost
```

In this post I have used `<a_user>` for the user on **A** and `<b_user>` as tokens for the user on **B**.